# "Data source name not found" when using unixODBC connection

Tags: sql-server, django, unixodbc

I am getting this error from `views.py`:

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not
>   found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')

Here is  `views.py` to save the database data to a json file

```
connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=dev_appserver;DATABASE=DemoApp;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
            SELECT book_id, book_name, author_name, publisher_name, email, bookref
            FROM Book
            """)

rows = cursor.fetchall()


rowarray_list = []
for row in rows:
    t = (row.book_id, row.book_name, row.author_name, row.publisher_name, 
         row.email, row.bookref)
    rowarray_list.append(t)

j = json.dumps(rowarray_list)
rowarrays_file = 'student_rowarrays.json'
f = open(rowarrays_file,'w')
print >> f, j

objects_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = collections.OrderedDict()
    d['book_id'] = row.book_id
    d['book_name'] = row.book_name
    d['author_name'] = row.author_name
    d['publisher_name'] = row.publisher_name
    d['email'] = row.email
    d['bookref'] = row.bookref
    objects_list.append(d)

j = json.dumps(objects_list)
objects_file = 'student_objects.json'
f = open(objects_file,'w')
print >> f, j

conn.close()
```

This is coded to write the database data to a json file

Thanks

Comment: How do you configure your odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files? BTW, if possible, could you use strace command to track view.py?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be passing a username or password when you connect to the database.

Try something like this:

```
connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=dev_appserver;DATABASE=DemoApp;UID=username;PWD=password'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
```